# R prevent overlap in pie charts

Tags: r

My data is like this:

```
 VariantClass   PASS_ONTARGET
  Silent            50.30
  Missense          47.00
  Nonsense           0.74
  Startloss          0.26
  Stoploss           0.74
  Frameshift-indel   0.61
  Inframe-indel      0.35
```

and my code for generating pie chart is:

```
    data <- read.table(file=Infilename, header=T, sep="\t")
    png(filename=Outfilename,height=4000,width=5000,res=600)
    y<-data$PASS_ONTARGET
    color<-c("blue","green","light blue","orange","purple","red","yellow")
    names<-c(data$VariantClass)
    pie(y, labels=names, font=2, main="Variant Class Distribution", clockwise = FALSE, density = NULL, col = color, border = NULL, lty = NULL)
    legend("topright",legend=names,cex=1.0, bty="n", fill=c(color))
    dev.off()
```

The problem I am getting is that the labels on the graph are overlapping each other. How can I prevent that?

Comment: With all due respect, please don't (ever) use pie charts. They provide almost no information.  Your data will be much better communicated with a Pareto chart (with or without the cumulative line).

Comment: But what is my senior asks me to put a pie chart only. Even I am not a fan of pie charts but this is a requirement for a larger project. Could you please help?

Comment: Ah, well, then, you're stuck :-( .

Answer (score 4):

Make the radius bigger and shrink the labels.

```
pie(<your other arguments>, radius = 1, cex = 0.3)
```

But like Carl said, [don't use pie charts](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf).

---

Here's a comparison of a pie plot and a bar plot for visualizing this dataset. To me, the bar plot makes comparisons easier.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)

dataset <- tribble(
  ~ VariantClass, ~ PASS_ONTARGET,
  "Silent",            50.30,
  "Missense",          47.00,
  "Nonsense",           0.74,
  "Startloss",          0.26,
  "Stoploss",           0.74,
  "Frameshift-indel",   0.61,
  "Inframe-indel",      0.35
) %>% 
  mutate(VariantClass = fct_reorder(VariantClass, PASS_ONTARGET))

ggplot(dataset, aes(x = "", y = PASS_ONTARGET, fill = VariantClass)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) + 
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  xlab(NULL)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(dataset, aes(VariantClass, PASS_ONTARGET)) +
  geom_col() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

For completeness, here are Pareto plot and waterfall plot alternatives. You need to calculate the cumulative y-values before plotting.

```r
dataset2 <- dataset %>% 
  arrange(desc(VariantClass)) %>% 
  mutate(
    cum_PASS_ONTARGET = cumsum(PASS_ONTARGET)
  )
```

The Pareto plot is a bar plot + cumulative total line. It's more information than the bar plot, which is useful if you want to answer questions like "how many of the biggest categories do I need to include to get to 90% of the total?". (This is important for PCA, where Pareto plots are common.) It squashes the bars compared to a standard bar plot though.

```r
ggplot(dataset2) +
  geom_col(aes(VariantClass, PASS_ONTARGET)) + 
  geom_line(aes(as.integer(VariantClass), cum_PASS_ONTARGET)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

The waterfall plot shifts bars to give a cumulative total. These are a bit niche, since they are only good for looking at cumulative totals: the individual bars now can't be compared. The Pareto plot is better than the waterfall plot for this use.

```r
ggplot(dataset2) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      x = VariantClass,
      xmin = as.integer(VariantClass) - 0.45, 
      xmax = as.integer(VariantClass) + 0.45, 
      ymin = cum_PASS_ONTARGET - PASS_ONTARGET, 
      ymax = cum_PASS_ONTARGET
    )
  ) + 
  coord_flip()
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when i reduce the cex it shrinks to non readable value. What i want to do is to increase the label ticks to point it out to separate regions to pin point the value

Comment: Hmm, then you may need to write the labels separately, using `text()`

Comment: Since your other groups are so small, why not combine them into a single "other" category?  It's not like you can accurately estimate the size of each tiny category from the pie chart anyway.

Comment: The 'save the pies for dessert' article you cite is crazy. In the build-up on p1-3 it corrects all the common issues with pie charts and culminates with the perfect graphic for a parts-to-whole visualization shown on the bottom of p3 (labels and percentages included!). Then it goes on to straw man the hell out of the pie chart by making bad axis numbering decisions on p8 and ridiculing the admittedly obnoxious 3D variants on p9. Pies are instantly recognizable as part-to-whole. Not so with the pareto graph alternative suggested. MPGA.

Comment: @RichieCotton, that is a good update to your post Richie, but I still think the pie chart is much easier to see.  The conclusion that we want to draw from this data is that only the Silent and Missense categories matter; Everything else contributes inconsequential amounts to the total volume. If you place the legend overtop of the pie sectors and replace the 0-25-50-75-100 with group percentages the pie chart would be even better.

Comment: To make an analogy, imagine if I gave a very precise explanation of a concept but switched languages from English to French to Russian to Japanese every sentence. This is a pareto bar chart. The viewer has to infer the part-to-whole. Now instead if I just got the general concept across but stuck with one language the entire time. This is a pie chart. I've gone through enough presentations with people who only want the bottom line to know there are some situations where pareto-bar charts are the wrong approach, even if the pareto-bar objectively has more information.

Comment: One way to further improve the pareto-bar chart is to give it a second axis, one for values, and one for percentages. `scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./ sum(df$value), name = "Volume %", label=percent))`